# How to change linked table in Access from ODBC to local Access DB

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access database that contain linked tables to SQL Server database. Now I Want to change all linked table to link it with local Access Database , 
it's possible to do that ?

Comment: Search for "relink tables" e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416747/relinking-database-tables-access-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for what I want exactly.
This command will link to the Table from another Database:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", "D:\ Database Path ", acTable, " Source Table ", " Destination "
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a longer solution than what you are looking for but,

If you right click on the table in your navigation pane you can select "Convert to local table"

then you can split your database